# Basic Object Oriented Design java

Tags: java, oop, object

I really don't understand the principle of Object Oriented Design?? 
So I have classes

Map class holds rooms and connects all of rooms , places all of hazards randomly into rooms, return the particulate room, and  return the random rooms.

and

Player class that play turns, move player from room to another, shoot into rooms  and play games.

also

Room class as follow.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Room
{
    private int myRoomID;
    private ArrayList<Room> myNeighbours;

    private boolean myHasBats;
    private boolean myHasPit;
    private boolean myHasWumpus;

    public Room(int id) {
        myRoomID = id; 
        myNeighbours = new ArrayList<Room>();
    }

    public int getRoomID() {
        return myRoomID;
    }

    public ArrayList<Room> getNeighbours() {
        return myNeighbours;
    }

    public void connectTo(Room room) {
        myNeighbours.add(room);
    }    

    public boolean hasBats() {
        return myHasBats;
    }

    public void setHasBats(boolean flag) {
        myHasBats = flag;
    }

    public boolean hasPit() {
        return myHasPit;
    }

    public void setHasPit(boolean flag) {
        myHasPit = flag;
    }

    public boolean hasWumpus() {
        return myHasWumpus;
    }

    public void setHasWumpus(boolean flag) {
        myHasWumpus = flag;
    }

    public void checkBats() {
        boolean bats = false;
        for (Room r : myNeighbours) {
            if (r.hasBats()) {
                bats = true;
            }
        }
        if (bats) {
            System.out.println("I hear squeaking!");
        }
    }

    public void checkPit() {
        boolean pit = false;
        for (Room r : myNeighbours) {
            if (r.hasPit()) {
                pit = true;
            }
        }
        if (pit) {
            System.out.println("I feel a draft!");
        }
    }

    public void checkWumpus() {
        boolean wumpus = false;
        for (Room r : myNeighbours) {
            if (r.hasWumpus()) {
                wumpus = true;
            }
        }
        if (wumpus) {
            System.out.println("I smell a wumpus!");
        }
    }

    public boolean enter(Player player) {
        System.out.println("You are in Room " + myRoomID);
        System.out.print("Exits lead to rooms");

        for (Room r : myNeighbours) {
            System.out.print(" " + r.getRoomID());
        }
        System.out.println();
        checkBats();
        checkPit();
        checkWumpus();

        if (myHasBats) {
            System.out.println("A flock of bats picks you up and carries you off to another room!");
            return player.moveRandom();
        }
        else if (myHasPit) {
            System.out.println("You fall into a bottomless pit!");
            return true;
        }
        else if (myHasWumpus) {
            System.out.println("You have been eaten by a wumpus!");            
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

public boolean shoot()


        if (myHasWumpus) {

            System.out.println("You killed the Wumpus!");

            return true;


        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Your arrow falls with a clatter to the floor!");

            return false;


        }

    }
```

And I want to change this so that the wumpus needs to be shot more than once (you choose how many times) to be killed. Each time it is shot it runs to a random neighbouring room (not the one the player is in).

I am assuming that I need to change `public boolean shoot()` method into loop and call `public Room getRandomRoom()` as below.

But I really don't understand how to do this, especially because the use of boolean method is very confusing to me.
Does anyone know where I can find a information to learn the basic's of Object Oriented Design?

```
    public Room getRandomRoom() {

        Random rng = new Random();

        int i = rng.nextInt(Map.NUM_ROOMS);  

        return myRooms.get(i);

  }
```

Later on we are going to use `implements` in the class to separate all of hazards into classes. but for not they are all in Map and Room class.

Comment: I guess I only needed to post `public boolean shoot()` method, but I am so stack with this that I don't know where to start even....

Comment: @user1721548 Well go ahead and do that now. It's preferrable for your questions to have the smallest scope that is useful to you (make more questions if necessary), instead of a single question going on about every thing that occured to you while doing your assignment or whatever.

Comment: @user1721548 Doing this will both help us give you a better answer quicker as there's less to take in at once, and it will probably help you in reasoning about your design if you have to decompose it into the isolated problems you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without a wumpus class that's going to be messy and limited and even more inefficient. Your problem isn't that you don't get OO, it's that you are being restricted from using it.

Without out the class.
You are goingto have to add a myWumpusShotCount to room
Then in your shoot function, add 1 to it, test to see if it's 3 and if so kill it else random choose a room and set hasWumpus and WumpusShotCount in it

If you had a wumpus class it would have a property room , and another for how many bullets it had shipped and a behaviour when shot, ie the state of the wumpus and the behaviours of wumpus would be implemented by wumpus, not room. That's OO.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for calling `getRandomRoom() `? Am I using getter method? Please see the second answer.

Comment: By what you've described it doesn't have to be public, also if it were me I'd add a static property of type Random to the room class and make getRandomroom a static function as well. You don't need to 8instance a new one for each call. A tip start with private methods and then make them kore visible. Making sometimng private public, later on is way easier than making some thing public, private....

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Tony Hopkinson, I have come up with this code but it doesn't compile yet. It says can not find symbol - method `getRandomRoom() To call the method`getRandomRoom();` from Map class.
To send wumpus to the room another room randomly

```
public boolean shoot() {

 if (myHasWumpus) {
   myWumpusShotCount = 3;
   for(int i = 0; i< myWumpusShotCount; i++){
      if(myWumpusShotCount<=i){ 
          System.out.println("You killed the Wumpus!");
          return true;
      }
      else {
         Room wRoom = getRandomRoom(); 
         System.out.println("You killed the Wumpus!");
         return false;
         myWumpusShotCount++;

      }

        System.out.println("Your arrow falls with a clatter to the floor!");
        return false;
}


         System.out.println("You killed the Wumpus!");
         return true;
      }
   }
        System.out.println("Your arrow falls with a clatter to the floor!");
        return false;
}
```